# Json extractor make HTTP request stop

Tags: json, jmeter, components, extractor

After i installed jmeter component from link [enter link description here][1][1]: https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components, i create HTTP request to login  and use json extractor to get access token from login response, but when i run the request, this sample does not appear in View results tree listener.

When i run the test plan in other machine, this request work normal although version of jmeter, java are same.

Who can expand to me what's wrong in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the plugin from [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) - you need the "ExtrasLibs" one.

If problem persists - the first place to get to the bottom of the issue is *jmeter.log* file.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for installation and usage instructions.